# UITableViewCell AccessoryType accessibility hint?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiaccessibility

I've a `UITableViewCell` with the `accessoryType` set to be `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton`.  This displays the chevron and the info button.  When i check the accessibility inspector on the simulator, this has an `accessibiityHint` of "*More Info*"  is there any way to change this?

I have tried accessing it via the `accessoryView` property but this is nil.

(More context, my row selection cause the row to be selected, the detail disclosure triggers a segue to an edit screen. So the row `accessibilityHint` is along the lines of "*selects x*" and I'd like the info button to say "*Edits x*")

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I'm trying to figure it out too.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the cell's `accessoryType` to be `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton`, the info icon together with the disclosure indicator is accessible with a fixed `accessibilityLabel` of value `More info`. I suspect this is not changeable.

You can either change to use `UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator` as your cell's `accessoryType` or use your custom view as `accessoryView`. Then you can set your cell's `accessibilityLabel` or `accessibilityHint` as you like.